# Authenticate/Read/Write NFC Mifare Classic Using Private Key

Tags: rfid, mifare, apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

With refrence to [Michael Roland's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23670911/%E2%80%A6), I am facing problems in changing the key of a Mifare Classic 4K card. I want to do the personalization of NFC cards using NFC reader ACR122U.

I have followed the steps defined in this answer, and successfully read and write the sector trailer block 11 (by reading I got the 2 access bytes and 1 general purpose byte), as

```
00 00 00 00 00 7F 07 88 40 00 00 00 00 00
```

Using these access bytes and the new keys KeyA (`D6 DF 20 AE AE BC`) and KeyB (`D6 DF 20 AE AE BC`), I generate 16 byte (`D6 DF 20 AE AE BC ...`), along with access bytes to change the sector keys. I.e. write to block 11 with following 16 bytes:

```
D6 DF 20 AE AE BC   7F 07 88 40   D6 DF 20 AE AE BC
```

The write command thus becomes

```
FF D6 00 11 10 D6 DF 20 AE AE BC 7F 07 88 40 D6 DF 20 AE AE BC
```

The command executed successfully but when I authenticated block 8 (1st block of same sector), using Key B (0x61) and key (1 or 0), the authentication failed and returns 0x63. Which means sector 2 becomes inaccessible.

Also after then read and write to that sector failed.

Also [Android App NFCTagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) shows following

> Data (US-ASCII), Shows Sector 2: Read Failed!
>
> Access Conditions : Sector 2 (Could not read access conditions!)

Comment: Could you share your authenticate command?