# Bit Order Of Trailor Sector in Mifare Classic 4k

Tags: c#, nfc, rfid, mifare

With reference to section 8.7.1 to 8.7.3 [NFC Mifare Spec Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616263/set-own-authentication-keys-mifare-classic-with-apdu-c-sharp/23670911#23670911). I need to know the bit order of the trailor sector bytes, i.e. byte 6, 7, 8. So that I can do further processing on the trailor Sector i.e. write new key with access bytes to trailor sector, because as I write to the trailor sector it becomes inaccessible.

For byte 6, I am not clear that either

```
bits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

or

```
 bits 7,8,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

of byte 6 of trailor sector means

```
~C10    ~C11    ~C12    ~C13    ~C20    ~C21    ~C22    ~C23
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, your platform and the NFC/smartcard reader front-end will care about the transmission bit order. Hence, you don't really need to care about that.

Regarding the access bits, these map to the access bytes (bytes 6-8 of the sector trailer) like this (bit 7 is the most significant bit and bit 0 the least significant bit):

```
Bit:      7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0
Byte 6: ~C23 ~C22 ~C21 ~C20 ~C13 ~C12 ~C11 ~C10
Byte 7:  C13  C12  C11  C10 ~C33 ~C32 ~C31 ~C30
Byte 6:  C33  C32  C31  C30  C23  C22  C21  C20
```

Hence, in oder to set

- C1<sub>3</sub> = 0 (=> ~C1<sub>3</sub> = 1)
- C1<sub>2</sub> = 1 (=> ~C1<sub>2</sub> = 0)
- C1<sub>1</sub> = 1 (=> ~C1<sub>2</sub> = 0)
- C1<sub>0</sub> = 0 (=> ~C1<sub>2</sub> = 1)
- C2<sub>3</sub> = 1 (=> ~C2<sub>3</sub> = 0)
- C2<sub>2</sub> = 0 (=> ~C2<sub>2</sub> = 1)
- C2<sub>1</sub> = 0 (=> ~C2<sub>2</sub> = 1)
- C2<sub>0</sub> = 0 (=> ~C2<sub>2</sub> = 1)
- C3<sub>3</sub> = 0 (=> ~C3<sub>3</sub> = 1)
- C3<sub>2</sub> = 0 (=> ~C3<sub>2</sub> = 1)
- C3<sub>1</sub> = 1 (=> ~C3<sub>2</sub> = 0)
- C3<sub>0</sub> = 1 (=> ~C3<sub>2</sub> = 0)

You would use set byte 6 = `0x79`, byte 7 = `0x6C`, byte 8 = `0x38` (note that those values were chosen to make it clear how the bits map to the bytes and that those values do not necessarily make any sense in practice).

Comment: I am lost. The higher sectors have 16 blocks. How is the access bits configured for a sector with 16 blocks??

Comment: @eigenfield Coding is the same. CX_3 is exactly the same as for 4-block sectors (sector trailer access). The other flags apply to groups of 5 blocks: CX_0 applies to blocks 0..4, CX_1 applies to blocks 5..9, and CX_2 applies to blocks 10..14.

Comment: Thank you. I also figured it out and answered my own question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007809/mifare-4k-access-bits-on-higher-sectors-with-16-blocks/66010202#66010202