# Mifare 4k access bits on higher sectors with 16 blocks

Tags: mifare

Every answer so far is valid for sectors with 4 blocks. However, I cannot find in the spec or in any existing answer how is the access bits configured for higher sectors with 16 blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spec googlings and readings, I read in [in a spec](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S70YYX_V1.pdf) which has the below table:

[image]

Therefore, for sectors 32-39 in Mifare 4k, the access conditions is no longer per block but instead shared by blocks as outlined in the above table.